# How to connect NEAR Rainbow Bridge with my own Ethereum infra?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to understand what parts of config I need to modify.

```
{
        "nearNetworkId": "testnet",
        "nearNodeUrl": "https://rpc.testnet.near.org/",
        "ethNodeUrl": "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<project_id>",
        "nearMasterAccount": "<near_token_holder_account>",
        "nearMasterSk": "<near_token_holder_sk>",
        "nearClientAccount": "ethonnearclient10",
        "nearProverAccount": "ethonnearprover10",
        "nearClientTrustedSigner": "eth2nearrelay10.testnet",
        "ethMasterSk": "<eth_token_holder_sk>",
        "ethEd25519Address": "0x9003342d15B21b4C42e1702447fE2f39FfAF55C2",
        "ethClientAddress": "0xF721c979db97413AA9D0F91ad531FaBF769bb09C",
        "ethProverAddress": "0xc5D62d66B8650E6242D9936c7e50E959BA0F9E37",
        "ethErc20Address": "0x8151a8F90267bFf183E06921841C5dE774499388",
        "ethLockerAddress": "0x5f7Cc23F90b5264a083dcB3b171c7111Dc32dD00",
        "nearFunTokenAccount": "mintablefuntoken11"
}
```

I have my own infura for rinkeby
I have my own erc20 token on rinkeby

What is `nearMasterAccount`?
Where can I get `nearMasterSk`?
What is `ethMasterSk`?

In following command:

```
rainbow transfer-eth-erc20-to-near --amount 10 --eth-sender-sk <eth_token_holder_address> --near-receiver-account <near_token_holder_account>
```

`eth_token_holder_address` is it my own eth address?
`--eth-sender-sk` - looks like it should be my eth private key. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

> `eth_token_holder_address` is it my own eth address? `--eth-sender-sk` - looks like it should be my eth private key. Is this true?

Yes, this is true.

This command will send ERC20 tokens from a given [Rinkeby](https://support.airswap.io/en/articles/2831385-what-is-rinkeby) Ethereum account to a given NEAR [Testnet](https://docs.near.org/docs/roles/developer/networks#testnet) account. The other values you are looking for are also related to these two accounts:

```
"nearMasterAccount": "<near_token_holder_account>",
"nearMasterSk": "<near_token_holder_sk>",
"ethMasterSk": "<eth_token_holder_sk>",
```

Here's how to find this info.

### For Ethereum

1. Install [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/)
2. Switch to the Rinkeby network in the MetaMask UI
3. Generate a new account (public/private keypair) which you only intend to use with Rinkeby (you'll be able to use your mainnet accounts, but you wouldn't want to accidentally leak a mainnet private key, so be careful!)
4. Switch to this new account in the MetaMask UI. Click on the account name to copy it to clipboard. **This is your `eth_token_holder_address`**
5. In the current MetaMask UI, once I've selected an account, I can click a triple dot icon (`•••`) near the top right, click "Account Details", and then there's an "export private key" option. **This is your `eth_token_holder_sk`**

### For NEAR

1. Create an account at wallet.testnet.near.org – remember the account name you use, **this is your `near_token_holder_account`**
2. Open up your terminal, and install [near-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/near-cli)
3. Run `near login`. This will open wallet.testnet.near.org and allow you to select which account you'd like to authorize in near-cli. Select the account you created above.
4. The above command added a [Full Access key](https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/account#access-keys) to your account, and saved its private key to your local filesystem. You can find it by looking in your home directory, `~`, in a folder called `.near-credentials`. For me, the full path to this file is `~/.near-credentials/default/chadoh.json`. Open this file, copy the private key. **This is your `near_token_holder_sk`**